# Stop movieclip from scaling during full screen

Tags: flash

I've made an as3 projector application which has few buttons and flvplayback component.  When played in 1024x768 everything works fine. But if I run in a higher resolution monitors, the video gets Pixelated

So I need a way to stop the flvbplayback component from scaling, but other elements can scale along with stage.